# Regression and stress management

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

Participants were randomly allocated to one of two stress management therapy groups (group A vs. group B), or a waiting list control group. Their baseline levels of stress were measured before treatment, and again after 3 months of weekly therapy sessions. Therefore, the covariate in the model is baseline stress levels. How can one write a regression equation that represents this experiment?

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_E$ be the endpoint stress level, $S_B$ the baseline stress level, $A$ and $B$ groups $A$ and $B$ respectively, hence a possible regression model is
$$
S_E = \beta_0 +\beta_1S_B+\beta_2A + \beta_3B + \epsilon
$$